# Granting permissions to an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm fairly new to AWS, and I'm trying to grant a user access to an S3 bucket.
I've created an IAM user, and have the access key and secret access key ID associated with the user, but I'm struggling to figure out how to grant that user permissions to an S3 bucket. I'd like to grant them write access (but not read) to the bucket, but am starting with all access to see if I can get permissions working.

I tried creating a policy through the policy creation tool and then attaching the policy to the user, but when I try to access the bucket through the policy simulator I get an error 'Implicitly denied no matching statements'

Here is the policy the policy generator created:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1451195578000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::techp.websitebackup/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I think tried to attach this policy to the bucket in S3, but I get an error: Statement is missing required element - Statement "Stmt1451195578000" is missing "Principal" element

I think I'm probably misunderstanding how permissions on AWS work, can you provide some guidance?

thx
v

Comment: I suppose that you use not root account to attach the policy to bucket.

Comment: You're not far off.  The Principal is the entity (user, in this case) that is the subject of the policy.  If this is a bucket policy, you need to specify the users to whom it applies.  If you used this as a user policy (in IAM) the principal is implied.  Also, starting with granting all privileges is good thinking on your part.  It's a common mistake to grant what you think you'll need, not realizing what all those things might be.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Michael - that makes sense, also makes sense why I don't get errors attaching policy to user, but do get errors attaching to the bucket (since it needs a principal)

Answer (score 2):

Associating your policy with the user is the correct way of doing so. Your policy document is also correct.

In the simulator, don't provide * as the ARN of the resource but provide a qualified name. For example, `arn:aws:s3:::techp.websitebackup/*` or `arn:aws:s3:::techp.websitebackup/foo/bar` (because the user does not have privileges on every bucket in your account)

[image]